# How to retrieve variables as a parameter in a C++ function

Tags: c++, function, return-type

I want to do something simple. I want to have a custom function that returns multiple WCHAR values via its function's parameters. So, it may or may not take in a value to change the outgoing WCHAR parameters, or it just may have one outgoing parameter. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
int GetFolderName(WCHAR sOutValue)
{
wcscpy(sOutValue, L"E:\\temp");
}
```

I want my code to call this function and then get the value from it:

```
int main()
{
WCHAR *sFolder =  (WCHAR*)calloc(64,sizeof(WCHAR));
GetFolderName(...);
}
```

How do I declare GetFolderName and how do I call it?

```
int GetFolderName(WCHAR sOutValue);
```

or
    int GetFolderName(WCHAR *sOutValue);
or
    int GetFolderName(WCHAR **sOutValue);
or
    something else???

Getting a bit confused here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try `int GetFolderName(WCHAR *sOutValue)`?

Comment: How do I call it? `GetFolderName(sFolder);`?

Comment: Yep.  Not to sound rude but it sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was getting confused about how it was getting passed. I've got so much code I've been reviewing, I'm questioning myself!

Comment: Is there a reason to declare a function parameter with two `**`? Like `int GetFolderName(WCHAR **sOutValue);`?

Comment: If you need to modify the data a pointer points to, it is fine to just pass the pointer by value.  If you need to modify what a pointer actually points to, then you need to pass it by pointer or reference so you can change it.  If not all you are doing is changing a copy of the pointer, not the pointer from the call site.

Comment: I've used the `**` when I'm allocating memory in the function itself, as opposed to allocating it before the function. Makes for cleaner code to me.

Comment: That is a valid use case.  You can also use `*&` instead to make working with the pointer in the function easier.  You avoid all of the extra dereferencing.

Comment: This looks like C, not C++